# Output non-ASCII character to the console in C++ using repl.it

Tags: c++, replit

I am using repl.it to edit and compile some C++ code. I want to output the obelus (division sign) to the console. The following code should do it.

```
char div_sign ='\366';
cout << div_sign << endl;
```

This works in Visual Studio and from what I can find out it should work with any compiler. However, I do not get the correct output. The only thing I can think of is the repl does not use the OEM character set. Any suggestions to get this to work correctly in repl?

Comment: Isn't it `'\367'`, not `'\366'`?

Comment: ```'\367'``` Does not work in repl.it either. However, in Visual Studio, ``` '\366' ``` does out put a ÷ on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only thing I can think of is the repl does not use the OEM character set

This is correct.

`\366` (`0xF6`, `246`) is the character code for ÷ in the OEM-US/CP437 codepage.

repl.it treats what you write to `std::cout` as UTF-8. The Unicode codepoint for the same character is `\367` (`0xF7`, `247`).

Encoding that to UTF-8 gives us:

```
  std::cout << "\303\267";
```

which gives the expected output on repl.it

Comment: Is there a general way to get something to work for all runtime environments so we don't need to change the code to get it to work both places?